# Strange results in gdb

Tags: gcc, assembly, gdb, machine-code, memory-address

I am reading a C book that deals a lot with asm and looking at registers and memory with GDB.
The issue is, when I compile and disassemble the exact same source (actually using the source files that came WITH the book cd), the assembly instructions look quite a bit different than what's in the book.
The book uses intel flavored assembly and I am putting "set disassembly intel" in gdb, so it's not that.. just the instructions are in different order, some are all together different, and there are a few other quirks.

For instance, in the book there is a mov instruction in the eip register:

```
(gdb) x/i $eip
mov DWORD PTR[ebp-4], 0x0
```

corresponding to initializing the variable i to 0, in a for loop (i = 0, i<10, i++)

However, in my gdb console, with the breakpoint at the same place (set break main; run) I see this:

```
(gdb) x/i $eip
mov DWORD PTR[esp+0x1c], 0x0
```

notice it's referencing a different register all together - esp instead of ebp
if I check the value of esp, it's 0x1c itself. But if I try examine what's at 0x1c, or at esp+0x1c, it tells me that I am not able to look at those addresses

So as the book goes on, I can't follow along at all, because it starts following the trail of what's in ebp, ebp-4, and so on, and in my asm there doesn't seem to be anything happening with the ebp register

The book was written in 2008, so I can't imagine its so out of date that a version change of gcc or gdb would introduce that significant of a change (or did it?)... is it possible there is some compiler optimization or something switched on by default that is producing such different results?

Thanks in advance

Edit: Strange. I tried each of the suggestions and nothing worked. Then I did rm a.out and recompiled fresh and now it works fine (the instructions are different than the book still but I can examine the address corresponding to that of the book; as long as I can follow a corresponding pattern all is well, doesn't have to be the exact same asm, that would just make it too easy!) 
Thanks again for all your help and suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all going to be very platform and compiler specific. I'm afraid there's no much you can do.

Comment: Thanks. The book is using 32 bit intel as am I. both compiling with gcc (I will need to check versions and update the qeustion), running linux. The book is based on Ubuntu (again will need to check the version) and I am running an up to date Arch installation. 
I would assume with same architecture and same compiler (gcc) the machine-code would be the same no?
Either way, I find it weird that a value is being initialized into an address I can't examine, and also weird that it's being referenced by $esp i.e. the stack pointer...

Comment: No, no reason it should be the same. You can play with `-O0` or `-march=i386`. But it's not surprising that it would be completely different.

Answer (score 1):

There are a million things that could cause this. If you compiled your code on a different architecture, I'd expect this (and no, that doesn't even necessarily mean 32 vs 64 bit -- literally any different CPU architecture at all can change the execution order as I'll explain). If you compile your programs with optimizations, it will change the ordering of the execution to best exploit your CPU's pipeline. This may mean adding some NOOP instructions, or re-ordering them entirely (within reason, of course). Futhermore some CPUs have multiple ways of doing things, one way usually being faster than the other (the intel LOOP instruction comes to mind -- modern compilers avoid this instruction like the plague because it's terrible). If one register is more efficient than another, it will use it.

The moral of the story: for learning purposes both the author and the reader need to have all optimizations disabled. Also for added bonus points: use the same version of gcc and the same platform.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Thats kind of what I'm wondering, how can I force no optimizations. I understand that exact memory addresses and even the instructions may vary from architecture to architecture, that's the point of compilers, but I'm just surprised that it's this much different - even following the the asm seems to be a different program all together (it's nothing but a for loop in main so pretty straightforward to follow)
Really though the problem is it is saying the value is initialized in an address I can't examine(esp+0x1c), which shouldn't be the case

Comment: @rootlicker `gcc -O0` (that's letter O followed by number 0)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the code you compiled was compiled with `-fomit-frame-pointers`, which became the default with GCC-4.6.

Try building with explicit `-fno-omit-frame-pointer`. I expect the results will look much closer to the book.